# When sending GET through jQuerys load the variables are not available

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get, undefined

I am using jQuery to GET the contents of a navigation file and load it into a div on part of my page.

I am supplying it a value containing the page name so I can update the "active" class on the navigation.

Here is the code I am using to show the GET information, this works flawlessly as when I pass it a variable from my browser (i.e header.html?page=foo) it works perfectly.

```
<script>
    function getQueryParams(qs) {
        qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");
        var params = {},
            tokens,
            re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
        while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
            params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
                = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
        }
        return params;
    }
    var $_GET = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
    alert($_GET["page"]);
</script>
```

As you can see at the moment it just shows an alert with the value.

When I am calling this page, It is as simple as:

```
<script>
   $("#header").load("header.html?page=bar");
</script>
```

For the life of me I cannot understand why it is coming back as "undefined" when called from the .load, as I have used it many times before with GET variables.

Any input would be much appreciated,

Kris.

Comment: It's an AJAX call, so there's no new `document` associated with its response. The `document.location.search` referenced by that script is the same as the one in the page making the call, which I assume doesn't have a `page` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Javascript is being run by `.load`, the `document` is the original document, not the page being loaded.

To pass parameters to the script being loaded, use a global variable.

Comment: Aha, that makes sense to me. Is there a way to achieve this without using any server side scripting languages? In theory I would be able to refer to a variable if the JS is being loaded on that page.

Comment: Put the query parameters in a global variable, and have the JS check that variable.

Comment: That has worked, much appreciated! That has been bugging me for ages!